# Dimensionality specification for batch of matrix RV (e.g. Wishart dist)

Tags: pymc3, pymc

I'm currently constructing a Dirichlet Process Mixture Model with **multivariate normal** likelihood and *truncation*-based definition. To be specific, this is a mixture of $K$ components, each related with a mean parameter *mu* and inverse covariance matrix *tau*, and a normal distribution $N(mu, tau^{-1})$. The data include $N$ observations, with $d$ features.

In my construction of the model, I want each mixture component to have its own distinct mu's and tau's. Therefore, I have to specify **explicity** the batchsize, i.e. the number of components, in the definition of the variable, like this:

```
    mus = pm.MvNormal("mu", tbar, cov=np.eye(d)/0.1, shape=(K,d))
```

However, this becomes a little confusing when it comes to the definition of covariance/precision matrix. I've tried several ways to specify the shape parameter, but they all lead me to some error. (I've tried `shape=(K,)`, which i think will be simply ignored by the program; and also `shape=(K,d)`, `shape=(K,d,d)`, which all raised some error.) I also tried to change the shape of the parameter `nu` to include the batch information **implicitly**, which also raised an error. How should I specify this batchsize with matrix-valued random variables like this?

As i tried visualizing the model, which is defined by the chunk below, I found it has observations of dimensionality $N\times N$, which is not expected. (I'm expecting $N\times d$). Here is my code:

```
with pm.Model(coords={"component": np.arange(K), "obs_id": np.arange(N), "feature": np.arange(d)}) as model:
    alpha = pm.Gamma("alpha", 1.0, 1.0)
    w = pm.StickBreakingWeights("w", alpha, K-1)
    
    mus = pm.MvNormal("mu", tbar, cov=np.eye(d)/0.1, shape=(K,d))
    taus = pm.Wishart("taus", nu=d*np.ones(K), V=S_inv, shape=(K,))
    category = pm.Categorical("category", p=w, shape=N)

    obs = pm.MvNormal("obs", mu=mus[category], tau=taus[category], observed=df.values)
```

---

Besides, I've been wondering whether it's possible to *collapse* on the `category` variable, which is discrete and making it hard for the program to perform variational inference. Will using `Mixture` in the model help? (However this is not my major concern right now lol, i'm really struggling with dimensionality!)

Thanks for any tips or advice!